# Switch statement with string

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-7

I tried the following code:

```
String str = "Str1";

switch(str) {
    case Constants.First_String  : System.out.println("First String");
                                   break;
    case Constants.Second_String : System.out.println("Second String");
                                   break;
    default : System.out.println("Default String");
}
```

And my `Constants` class is,

```
public class Constants {
    public static String First_String  = "Str1";
    public static String Second_String = "Str2";
    public static String Third_String  = "Str3";
}
```

And I got a compilation error as,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: case expressions must be constant expressions

But when I tried with following code,

```
switch(str){
    case "Str1" : System.out.println("First String");
                  break;
    case "Str2" : System.out.println("Second String");
                  break;
    default : System.out.println("Default String");
}
```

No Compilation errors, and prints the output as,

```
First String
```

My question is, why in the first case compliation error occurs. And how can I resolve it.

Comment: Make your constants `final`. So `public static String First_String  = "Str1";` becomes `public static final String First_String  = "Str1";`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"Str1"` is a compile-time constant and that's why `case "Str"` is fine.

However, the from the definition of `First_String` we can see that it is not a constant, because it can change it's value at any time.

You can try setting it as `final`:

```
public static final String First_String  = "Str1";
```

Answer (score 4):

A [*constant expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) is not the same as a *static* member. Even a static member can be changed by code... It needs to be `final` to be [considered a constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

From [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/):

> A compile-time constant expression is an expression...
>
> - Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).

So

```
case "Something":
```

is OK. As is

```
public static final String ME = "Other";
...
case ME:
```

Finally, `enum`'s are also OK to use in `switch`-`case` statements.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public static String First_String  = "Str1";
```

to

```
public static final String First_String  = "Str1";
```

Now it is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The strings in your `Constants` class must be declared `final` to be regarded as constants.

If they are declared `final`, the compiler knows they can never change, so can treat them as constant expressions. If they are not declared `final`, the possibility exists they might be reassigned to different strings during the execution of the program, so they are not constants.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare `Constants` as `final`

```
public static final String First_String  = "Str1";
public static final String Second_String = "Str2";
public static final String Third_String  = "Str3";
```

Or transform `switch` in `if-else` statement:

**In Eclipse**
You can quickly convert a `switch` statement to an `if-else` statement using the following:

Move your cursor to the `switch` keyword and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> then select

> Convert 'switch' to 'if-else'.